# Align GPS position in GPX path

Tags: gps, maps, coordinates, gpx

Lets's imagine this. I have tracking devices sending their coordinates. I have a GPX and the map. Now, between point one and two (blue circle from bottom to top) the GPX have no points. The tracker reports his location, but is not tottally align with the line because of weak GPS signal or anything else. I want to align the marker in the GPX line even with no points.

Can i do it? Can you help guys? All comunication and service are in PHP

[image: gpx]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial problem but you should be able to solve it by utilizing some premade services. This post on [GIS StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64453/how-to-match-gps-collected-data-to-routes-on-google-maps) lists some services that can do this.